# Why must Tableau data sources always keep "Loading datasource for first time" for each one you choose to look at

Tags: tableau-api

I keep having to wait for several minutes every time I click on the Data Source tab in Tableau Desktop.  The wait can be 10 or 15 minutes, and I know it's not the first time for the data to load.

It's every time.  Why is this happening?  Please?  Does'nt the workbook know the data has been loaded?

This is the message... 
[image]

Comment: Hi, are you working with live connection or extracts? and, also please let us know which data source type like SQL, etc you are using?

Comment: Each data source is an text-file (.csv) extract which is also on my local laptop.   I have 9.  Most are relatively small but there are a couple larger ones, around 2gb.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're connecting them as a union  or all the data sources are connected separately, either ways I would highly recommend you to work on the dashboard by keeping data source in extract mode because of the following reasons:

Extract being columnar storage their performance is noticably fast, it reduces the load on the system and also you can do pre - aggregations aka aggregated extracts.

Hope this info helps.